# Clear textboxes Script not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this `form` and this `Script` but the `Script` doesn't work. I used it like a month ago and it worked, but it doesn't work now.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="depName" value="<?php echo $_GET['var'];?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="personStat" value="Espera">

    <div class="input1">FirstName :<input type="text" name="fname" class="in1" value="<?php echo $nombre;?>"> <span class="error1">* <?php echo $nombreErr;?></span> </div>

    <div class="input2">LastName :<input type="text" name="lname" class="in2" value="<?php echo $apellido;?>"> <span class="error2">* <?php echo $apellidoErr;?></span> </div>

    <div class="input3">2LastName :<input type="text" name="Slname" class="in3" value="<?php echo $segundoAppellido; ?>"> <span class="error1"><?php echo $segundoAppellidoErr; ?></span> </div>

    <div class="input4">Student Id :<input type="text" name="studentId" class="in4" value="<?php echo $idEstudiante;?>"> <span class="error2"><?php echo $idEstudianteErr; ?></span> </div>

    <input class="buttonClr" type="button" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Script

```
<script> //Funtion that works on buttonClr click
    $(".buttonClr").live('click',function(){ 
        $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"]').val(''); //Clear all textboxes
        $('Select').val(''); //Clear the multiple select
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's `.buttonClr` button?

Comment: instead of `.live()` use `.on()`

Comment: why do you need a script here? have you tried the `<input type="reset"`?

Comment: Yeah `<input type="reset">` works wonders too. Sorry, first time html/Php

Comment: As long as your PHP variables are all set to empty strings, then reset will clear the fields.  But if any of those PHP variables are set to any other string values, clicking reset will simply restore those defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you have updated your jquery to version 1.7 or above, so `live()` no longer works. Here's the explanation from [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Change your script as below

```
<script> //Funtion that works on buttonClr click
    $(".buttonClr").on('click',function(){ 
         $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"]').val(''); //Clear all textboxes
         $('Select').val(''); //Clear the multiple select
    });
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/16nu4aom/

Answer (score 1):

Try this script, for clearing the input fields:

```
 $(".buttonClr").bind('click',function(){ 
      $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"]').val(''); //Clear all textboxes
      $('Select').val(''); //Clear the multiple select
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use reset button instead of `JS`. Example:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="depName" value="<?php echo $_GET['var'];?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="personStat" value="Espera">
    <div class="input1">FirstName :<input type="text" name="fname" class="in1" value="<?php echo $nombre;?>"> <span class="error1">* <?php echo $nombreErr;?></span> </div>
    <div class="input2">LastName :<input type="text" name="lname" class="in2" value="<?php echo $apellido;?>"> <span class="error2">* <?php echo $apellidoErr;?></span> </div>
    <div class="input3">2LastName :<input type="text" name="Slname" class="in3" value="<?php echo $segundoAppellido; ?>"> <span class="error1"><?php echo $segundoAppellidoErr; ?></span> </div>
    <div class="input4">Student Id :<input type="text" name="studentId" class="in4" value="<?php echo $idEstudiante;?>"> <span class="error2"><?php echo $idEstudianteErr; ?></span> </div>
    <input class="buttonClr" type="reset" value="Clear">
                            <!---^^^^^^^-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If just want to reset all form fields, you just need to add reset button. That is the simplest way for 1 click resetting button.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
```